# Imputation of missing Values from a different Data Frame and generating many data frames

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, missing-data

I have the sample input file `DF1` out of many rows and columns with missing data and wanted to impute the missing data from a different data frame `DF2`and generate many data frames as shown in the output ans save as a data frame. Can anyone help in solving this issue.

Input:

```
DF1: 

GM  A   B   C   D   E
1   22  34  56  345 76
2   34  44  777 67  NA
3   45  76  77  NA  NA
4   56  88  NA  NA  NA
5   36  NA  NA  NA  NA

DF2

V1  V2  V3
1   11  21
2   12  22
3   13  23
4   14  24
5   15  25
6   16  26
7   17  27
8   18  28
9   19  29
10  20  30
```

Output:

OutputV1:

```
GM  A   B   C   D   E
1   22  34  56  345 76
2   34  44  777 67  1
3   45  76  77  2   3
4   56  88  4   5   6
5   36  7   8   9   10
```

OutputV2

```
GM  A   B   C   D   E
1   22  34  56  345 76
2   34  44  777 67  11
3   45  76  77  12  13
4   56  88  14  14  16
5   36  17  18  19  20
```

Output3:

```
GM  A   B   C   D   E
1   22  34  56  345 76
2   34  44  777 67  21
3   45  76  77  22  23
4   56  88  24  25  26
5   36  27  28  29  30
```

I did put the picture to make it clear for adding the values of DF2 to the output dataframe

OuputV1:

[image: FIrst Output]

OutputV2:

[image]

It would be great if someone help me in solving this as there area many variables in the DF2 and many data frames needs to be generated depending on the number of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose *DF1*, fill the missing values, and then transpose it back:

```
t_df <- t(df1)
t_df[is.na(t_df)] <- df2$V1
as.data.frame(t(t_df))

#  GM  A  B   C   D  E
#1  1 22 34  56 345 76
#2  2 34 44 777  67  1
#3  3 45 76  77   2  3
#4  4 56 88   4   5  6
#5  5 36  7   8   9 10
```

<sub>This works best if all columns have the same data type, otherwise the data types may get mixed up due to the transpose.</sub>

---

```
impute_by_row <- function(df, values) {
    t_df <- t(df)
    t_df[is.na(t_df)] <- values
    as.data.frame(t(t_df))
}

impute_by_row(df1, df2$V1)
#  GM  A  B   C   D  E
#1  1 22 34  56 345 76
#2  2 34 44 777  67  1
#3  3 45 76  77   2  3
#4  4 56 88   4   5  6
#5  5 36  7   8   9 10

impute_by_row(df1, df2$V2)
#  GM  A  B   C   D  E
#1  1 22 34  56 345 76
#2  2 34 44 777  67 11
#3  3 45 76  77  12 13
#4  4 56 88  14  15 16
#5  5 36 17  18  19 20

impute_by_row(df1, df2$V3)
#  GM  A  B   C   D  E
#1  1 22 34  56 345 76
#2  2 34 44 777  67 21
#3  3 45 76  77  22 23
#4  4 56 88  24  25 26
#5  5 36 27  28  29 30
```

---

Apply the function to all columns of `df2`:

```
lapply(df2, function(v) impute_by_row(df1, v))

$V1
  GM  A  B   C   D  E
1  1 22 34  56 345 76
2  2 34 44 777  67  1
3  3 45 76  77   2  3
4  4 56 88   4   5  6
5  5 36  7   8   9 10

$V2
  GM  A  B   C   D  E
1  1 22 34  56 345 76
2  2 34 44 777  67 11
3  3 45 76  77  12 13
4  4 56 88  14  15 16
5  5 36 17  18  19 20

$V3
  GM  A  B   C   D  E
1  1 22 34  56 345 76
2  2 34 44 777  67 21
3  3 45 76  77  22 23
4  4 56 88  24  25 26
5  5 36 27  28  29 30
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I have around 500 Variables to be needed to fill. Is there any way I can do that in loops.

Comment: `lapply(df2, function(v) impute_by_row(df1, v))` will give you a list of data frames with missing values imputed by columns from `df2`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the above equation 'lapply(df2, function(v) impute_by_row(df1, v))' is not working!  Can you please help me in solving this

Comment: I am getting a large list and when I did convert it to data frame it is giving only one observation of different variables. I need different data frames with the imputation of missing values to df1 from variables of df2

Comment: Doesn't the list contain data frames you need? Check individual element in the list, each element should be a data frame with missing values imputed.

Comment: Can you help me in finding the elements and converting it into the data frame as the required Dataframe object. I tried but not able to bring it in the proper format

Comment: `lst <- lapply(df2, function(v) impute_by_row(df1, v))`. Then `lst[[1]], lst[[2]] ...`

Comment: I tried doing that and coverted it into the dataframe `as.data.frame(lst[[1]])` but it is giving many variables in one row. It its not giving the proper Output Format

Comment: I don't think I am sure what you mean. The above gives me a list of three data frames, with each element corresponding to an output `v1, v2, v3`. What are the `class(df1)` and `class(df2)`? Are they data frames?

Comment: `class(df1)` gives me `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"` and the class of `df2`gives me `"data.frame"`

Comment: I updated the results with `lapply`, is it what you need?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, that is what I needed.